# How can I set reactdate-picker dropdown view to upper

Tags: reactjs

Normal style of drop down view is at bottom after click,HOw can I set to upper place.plz Let me fix that.
Here is my nomal datepicker in reactjs.

```
 <DatePicker
     selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
 />
```

Answer (score 6):

Add prop for `popperPlacement`, like this:

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  popperPlacement="top-start"
>
```

React DatePicker does that automatically if there is not enough room for it on the bottom of the page, but this way you can "force" it.

See [The source](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/src/popper_component.jsx) for additional placement options.